# Find inline Javascript and replace with the script result

Tags: javascript, replace, ide, find, text-editor

I have a huge old HTML website, and I need to clean it first in order to import its articles in Drupal CMS.

In some of the articles there are some javascript tags with code like this:

```
<p>Some text here 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var text = '&#104;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;' + '&#119;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;';
document.write(text);
</script> and some more text here</p>
```

How can I find and replace these tags with the result of the javascript code?
So my HTML files will be saved as:

```
<p>Some text here hello world and some more text here</p>
```

Please note that the output of these snippets is different from page to page.

Is this possible with ide's like Dreamweaver or any text editor?

Comment: you could write them to an text file and replace them manually. `writeTextFile("textfile.txt", "&#104;")`. In your editor you can then find and replace it.

Comment: Could use a headless browser on server to execute the script then parse resultant and write to file/database